# Phpmyadmin Sql Node.js // Automatic random messages and a fake User betting

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I have an website about Cs:go gambling site. (Www.csgofatwin.com) 
I want to put a fake person sending random messages in the chat already online in the site.
And i want to do a fake person betting on the site, as you can see in the link, there is 3 option to bet. 
I have been looking for everywhere and I dont find it how to do it.
The site works with Node.js, Phpmyadmin with mySql. 
If anyone could help me or just send a good tutorial how to do it, I would be very grateful.
Thank you.